# Some reflection technique to copy the SharePoint list in Summary Links

Tags: reflection, sharepoint-2010

Would there be a way to copy the entire list from the SharePoint Summary Links webpart?  Think it will be very useful and handy thing to have.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to being able to duplicate the configured summary links elsewhere in the web, you can do this:

- configure one summary links web part exactly as you want it
- export that web part from the dropdown menu at the top of the web part
- this export is an xml rendering of the configured links so that might be useful to you too
- upload that saved web part into the site collection web part gallery
- insert that new web part elsewhere to have a duplicate instance of the summary links
- note that the links have been saved as site relative so they should be good anywhere in the site collection

Comment: I just tried this out and what you suggested is simple and straight forward. Thanks,